# Search multiple words in a text file

Tags: c#, streamreader, file.readalllines

I made a code to search for several words in a text file but only the last word is searched, I would like to solve it
code:

```
string txt_text;
string[] words = {
  "var",
  "bob",
  "for",
  "example"
};
StreamReader file = new StreamReader("test.txt");
foreach(string _words in words) {
  while ((txt_text = file.ReadToEnd()) != null) {
    if (txt_text.Contains(_words)) {
      textBox1.Text = "founded";
      break;
    } else {
      textBox1.Text = "nothing founded";
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do not take into account the ``` was my fault when putting the code, that is not there in the original code

Comment: The procedure is searching for `a`. Change `if(txt_text.Contains("a"))` to `txt_text.Contains(_words)`.

Comment: @PoulBak, As written in the example `words` is an array, but `_words` is an array element. Actually, code's naming need to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can get rid of `StreamReader` and loop and *query* the file with a help of *Linq*

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

...

textBox1.Text = File
  .ReadLines("test.txt")
  .Any(line => words.Any(word => line.Contains(word))) 
     ? "found"
     : "nothing found";
```

If you insist on loop, you should drop `else`:

```
 // using - do not forget to Dispose IDisposable
 using StreamReader file = new StreamReader("test.txt");

 // shorter version is
 // string txt_text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
 string txt_text = file.ReadToEnd();

 bool found = false;

 foreach (string word in words) 
   if (txt_text.Contains(word)) {
     // If any word has been found, stop further searching
     found = true;

     break; 
   } // no else here: keep on looping for other words

 textBox1.Text = found
   ? "found"
   : "nothing found";
```

Comment: @vitem: Once you're able to, please mark Dmitry's answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it. That will mark this question as resolved, and reward Dmitry for his contribution. Don't explicitly mark your question as "closed" in the title (I've rolled back that change).

Answer (score 0):

I'd save the text in a variable and then loop over your words to check if it exists in the file. Something like this:

```
string[] words = { "var", "bob", "for", "example"};
var text = file.ReadToEnd();

List<string> foundWords = new List<string>();

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (text.Contains(word))
        foundWords.Add(word);
}
```

Then, the list `foundWords` contains all matching words.

(PS: Don't forget to put your `StreamReader` in a `using` statement so it gets disposed correctly)

Comment: I tried this but it still only looks for the word example